# Dynamically pass a parameter property inside react function

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to dynamically change the property of a parameter but everything I try does not work.

ideally I will pass this in the function

```
function APIDropDown ({ContID, API, FeildName, DDClass, DataProp}) {
```

The line I am looking to change is

```
<option key={index}>{data.Data_Feild}</option>
```

I have tried

```
<option key={index}>{data.{DataProp}</option>
```

The whole function looks like this

```
function APIDropDown ({ContID, API, FeildName, DDClass}) {
const [data, setData] = useState([]);  
useEffect(() => {
  var APIURL = 'http://localhost:4000'+API+'';
  axios
    .get(APIURL)
    .then((response) => {
      setData(response.data);
    })
    .catch(console.error);
}, []);
  return (
    <Form.Group className={DDClass} controlId={ContID}>
    <Form.Label>{FeildName}</Form.Label>
      <Form.Select aria-label={FeildName}>
      <option>--Select--</option>
      {data.map((data, index) => (
                    <option key={index}>{data.Data_Feild}</option>
                ))}
      </Form.Select>
    </Form.Group>
  ); 
}
export {APIDropDown};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to get property from data with key name passed as DataProp.

You can use this:

```
<option key={index}>{data[DataProp]}</option>
```